# creating a custom function between 2 different spreadsheets in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i am trying to make a function that take a column from spreadsheet A and paste it as a row on spreadsheet B (transposed), the function works as expected from the apps script editor, but when i try to call it from it's linked spreadsheet i get this error: "Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 6)."
this is the code for the function:

```
 function transposeColumn(colNum) {
      var srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("mySRCsheetID");
      srcLastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
      srcSheet = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      console.log(srcSheet[0][colNum - 1]);
      dataToCopy = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < srcLastRow; i++) {
        if (srcSheet[i][colNum - 1] == '') {
          break;
        } else {
          dataToCopy[i] = srcSheet[i][colNum - 1];
        }
      }
      console.log(dataToCopy);
      dataLength = dataToCopy.length;
      console.log(dataLength)
      var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var destCell = destSheet.getActiveCell();
      var cellCol = destCell.getRow();
      var cellRow = destCell.getColumn();
      for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        destSheet.getRange(cellRow, cellCol).setValue(dataToCopy[i]);
        cellCol++;
      }
    }
```

i need this function to run properly when i call it from the destination spreadsheet.

Comment: From your script, if you are executing the function `transposeColumn` as the custom function, such error occurs. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced) In that case, how about executing the function by the custom menu, the button, the checkbox, the OnEdit trigger and so on? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: can you tell me more please? how can i do this using any of these? i need to call the function in a cell and pass in it the column number i want to transpose here from the source sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `i need to call the function in a cell and pass in it the column number i want to transpose here from the source sheet `, I cannot understand about this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: i need to call my function in my destination sheet and pass in it as an argument the column i want to transpose from my source sheet "=transposeColumn(n)".
this means i need to start transposing column n from the source sheet to this cell in the destination sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, you are required to use `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl` in the custom function. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @YoussefAhmed as far as i know you can't use openById / DriveApp.xxx / and related stuff like that in a custom function. So you need to handle it like a macro. Use importrange with a parameter and the transpose function instead.

Comment: @tanaike yes, but i found the solution, will post it shortly. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: i found a way by adding a custom menu to my spreadsheet that includes my function, then call the function on the selected cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of simplest solution is here:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⚙ Scripts')
  .addItem('Get column', 'get_column')
  .addToUi();
}

function get_column() {
  var s_src = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("your_url");
  var col = s_src.getRange("A1:A").getValues().flat();
  var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,1,col.length);
  row.setValues([col]);
}
```

After reload you will get the menu
[image]

Perhaps you need to run the function `onOpen()` from Script Editor first time to get permissions.

This script copies column `A` from source spreadsheet and paste it as a `row 1` on active sheet.

[image]

If you need to get another columns (by its index or letter) it can be done. Let me know. For example you can put the index (or letter) of required column in current cell and script can read the number (or letter) from current cell. Or you can show a prompt message to input the index (or letter) of required column.

Comment: yess! thank you, that solved it for me. Your function to transpose is way more effecient than mine i didn't know some of these functions do exist!. Thanks a lot.